# algebraic system of planes

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to get a picture of intersection of several planes in 3d, with their algebraic system
something like 
[this](http://vegas.loria.fr/images/quadrics/intersections/cas_t3l11b.jpg):

[image: quadrics]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALFZe.jpg))

Comment: At second thought: Can you be more specific what you need? Just some image? Do you want to reproduce your given image by finding out the equations? Do you have equations and want to create a plot?

Comment: Are you looking for the all the tangent planes to this surface ?

Comment: I haven't got any equation, I'm looking for a picture something like you attached in the answer, but also with their equations

Answer (score 0):

Here:

[image: reproduction]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwI5R.png))

The above image shows the quadric surface
$$
y^2 + z^2  = 2 + x^2 \quad (*)
$$
(yellow colour), the planes $x=0$ and $y=0$ (purple colour).

The green and red curves are the intersections of $(*)$ with one of the planes each. Example:
$$
y^2 + z^2  = 2 + x^2 \wedge x = 0 \iff \\
y^2 + z^2 = 2
$$
which is a circle in the $y$-$z$-plane with radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: yes, that all I need, but I also need their equations system

Comment: thank you very much, but could you please give a picture of a bit different structure from the picture I attached ?

Comment: What do you mean by "different structure". I would suggest you fetch a copy of GeoGebra, open the 3D view and start playing with it. You can directly enter the equations and use the intersection tool to calculate intersections. I enjoy it. [You can download it](http://www.geogebra.org/download) for Windows, iOS, Android, Linux and even find an online version (but that one proably has no 3D support.

Comment: thank you very much , it is amazing